# multidimesional array with sql in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array in a variable called $ids, the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
        )

) etc
```

I need to use it in a WHERE id IN ($ids);
How do i go about it?
Thanks.

Comment: A bit rude considering how much time i've spent on this, don't just come here assuming i've been lazying around. If you can't answer the question move on to other questions jheez.

Comment: @Saff Nobody here knows how much time you have spent on it, and frankly it shouldn't matter if we did. We also don't want to waste our time giving you suggestions you have already tried. Letting people know what you have done is better for you as well as the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: The way you asked the question, it really gives the feeling you have been lazying around.. :)

Comment: haha sorry, it's probably just because i was fed up and tired lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement is a bit confusing. But you seem to want to know what you're trying to do, except you don't know how to compile the list of ids? If that is the case, try this:

```
$ids = array_map( function( $el ) {
    return $el['id'];
}, $array );
```

If you have a PHP version less than 5.3, you can't use anonymous functions. Use the code below instead.

```
function comb_arr( $el ) {
    return $el['id'];
}
$ids = array_map( 'comb_arr', $array );
```

Comment: It's showing "expected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'", do you know why that is?

Comment: No, because this works for me. You must have not copied it right or you're using an old PHP version, less than version 5.3.

Comment: Updated with a version that should work for you in case you don't have PHP version >= 5.3

Comment: Oh yh, you might be right. I'm using the current codeigniter framework.

Comment: Woo thanks a lot. It worked, i added join(',',$ids).

Answer (score 1):

try this...........

```
$data = Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
    )

 )  
$ids = array();

    foreach($data as $key => $d) {

      array_push($ids,$d['$id']);

   }

   $sql = "select * from tablename where id IN(implode(',',$ids))";
```

Comment: Thanks, i did try this but i have no clue why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you need to build the query using the array, i think you would basically want to build the query string, so you could use a for loop. start with a base string like

```
$query = "SELECT whatevercolumns FROM whatevertables WHERE id=";

//then loop through your array

for($j = 0; $j < sizeof($array); $j++)
{
     $query .= array[$j]

     //if it's not the last id you want to add, add an OR to your sql query
     if($j < (sizeof($array) - 1))
     {
          $query .= " OR ";
     }
}
```

it's not really clear what you're asking, you can't use sql to query your php array. i'm assuming you're wanting to use your array to populate an sql query.